# Messed up Blender models when exporting to Unity3D

Tags: export, external-applications, normals

I have modeled a simple pocket watch in Blender. Every time I import it into Unity3D, regardless of whether I export it from Blender as an FBX or 3ds file, it always comes out missing faces! Why is this happening? I have never had problems importing models into Unity3D like this before.

### Blender Screenshot

[image: Blender]

### Unity Screenshots

[image]
[image]

It seems to me that different faces appear when I rotate it differently. How can I prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just using the .blend file?

Comment: If you're using ngons, convert them to quads or tris first.

Comment: what direction are your face normals pointing at in blender?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like you have flipped normals.

Blender draws double-sided by default, but you can enable **Backface Culling** in the **Display** panel *(one of the panels right hand side of the view-port)*.

You can also enable drawing normals which draws a line in the direction each face points.

So you can use either of these draw options to check which way your normals are flipped.

This could be...

- Normals flipped the wrong way in Blender, you can select all in editmode and run '*Mesh -> Faces -> Recalculate Normals*' (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>). **OR** if they are **all** the wrong way around: you can simply flip the normals. '*Mesh -> Faces -> Flip Normals*')
- Negative scale on the object. Blender detects negative scaled objects and shows the faces pointing the right way, but many game engines will show normals flipped if you have a negative scaled object.

Comment: Flipping the normals worked great!

Comment: Thank you my scales were negative causing issues, wondering why just one object was going wrong in the scene!