# Vertex count at the top of the screen is inaccurate

Tags: mesh, export

I have one mesh and the object mode count is around 20,000 and the edit mode count on the mesh is 5,000. But when I export and import to unity it says it has more than the limit of vertices, so it splits it into 3 pieces. This is a big mistake... Unitys single mesh limit is 65,000 and it splits into 3... Help? It affects runtime and import/export time. I have a subsurf modifier but I know that's not the issue because when I take it off its around 1,000...

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ZiQtohl3tmRUhvbW5YMERjM0U/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: What format are you importing/exporting from/to? The subsurf modifier is set to 2 for render, which puts the mesh at 88K. Does deleting the subsurf modifier entirely help?

Comment: Let me try removing it, and fbx is my format

Comment: Even weirder, it fixed it but I have another issue that might connect to the problem.

I'm about to post a screenshot check the question in a minute.

Comment: That's a screenshot in unity... The whole back is missing?

Comment: It shows me the inside of the player whatever view I'm looking at. This is so strange...

Comment: See if [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/messed-up-blender-models-when-exporting-to-unity3d) answers your question. For future reference, we prefer to keep to one question per post to keep things organized and on-topic. However, you're welcome to write as many posts as you like.

Comment: I had to apply the modifier