# Invisible faces problem in Game Blender Engine

Tags: game-engine

How to fix the error shown on screeshots ? Thank you for your answers.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't a bug, but it rather looks like you've messed with the culling settings; https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/materials.html?highlight=culling. Try recalculating the faces or flipping them and turn backface culling off

Comment: To add to my previous comment; Backface culling is the progress of rendering unseen faces. Each face makes a draw call, and normally, only the faces seen by the camera should be rendered. Turning backface culling off, will allow *all* faces to be rendered. This will slow down the rendering time, but should not affect your game to a noticeable level with your polycount. For small games, you should disable backface culling. I do it myself for small games made in Blender as it makes it more resistant to visual abnormalities.

Comment: Thank you. Turning backface culling off was a good solution ! :)

Comment: Glad it helped you! If this answered your question, please consider marking my answer as the selected answer :)

Comment: @BBB Please use descriptive titles and fully describe the problem in the body of your post. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/messed-up-blender-models-when-exporting-to-unity3d

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  Not really, that questions answers this one but they are different questions.  See [this meta post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/549/5705).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely the result of flipped faces, resulting in this:
[image]

One way to fix this is to disable backface culling like so:
[image]

Or you could simply recalculate/flip normals of the faces:
[image]

Hope this helps.