# Models have missing parts when imported to blender

Tags: mesh, objects, import

[image]
Whenever I try to import a model in blender it has missing parts. For example I have a lot of invisible triangles, and whenever I import the model into a  game like gmod it still has broken triangles.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/messed-up-blender-models-when-exporting-to-unity3d

Comment: Does this happen for all models? I want to say try reinstalling blender. You can also attach an example model and I can try importing it to see if I get a similar result

Comment: i tried reinstalling blender, and factory reset to blender, and yes, it happens to all models.There is no point to send the model as it happens to any model i try to import. I resolved the part with game, in game is fine if i apply texture, but in blender it still looks broken. And before this a week ago it was working fine